# Page is responsive but not resizing on mobile properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://roomstonite.com/appstoreG.html is my page . When I open this page on mobile page is looking too small .. But when I resize it on browser it is takin full height .. Can anyone help why it is not covering full height on mobile ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a view port in your between your header tags

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

Set the viewport and initial scale:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```